# on change select option that will result different form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

So, I have a drop down list based on the user type. What i want is when user click  at different type of user, it will appear different.

```
<label for="user_type">Login Type:</label></td>
                    <td width="271"><select name="usertype" onChange="">
                      <option value="public">Public</option>
                      <option value="student"> Student</option
                    </select>
```

When user click at public, it will appear a form like this

```
  <p>Username 
    <label for="username"></label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  </p>
  <p>Password 
    <label for="password"></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </p>
```

And when user click at student, it will appear a form like this

```
 <p>Student ID 
    <label for="student_id"></label>
<input type="text" name="student_id" id="student_id">
  </p>
  <p>Password 
    <label for="password"></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: there is no question here... you simply provided a homework spec and expected others to do it for you. That's not how things work here. It is incumbent on you to show an attempt to solve issues yourself and when you have problems with real code provide that for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you buy yourself a book on DOM and javascript as this is a very basic example. With that said you can accomplish that like this:

```js
$('#toggler').change(function() {
  if ($('#toggler').val() === 'public') {
    $('#public').show();
    $('#student').hide();
  } else {
    $('#public').hide();
    $('#student').show();
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="usertype" id="toggler">
  <option value="public">Public</option>
  <option value="student">Student</option>
</select>


  <div id="public">
    <h2>Public</h2>
    <p>Username
      <label for="username"></label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>Password
      <label for="password"></label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
  </div>


  <div id="student">
    <h2>Student</h2>
    <p>Student ID
      <label for="student_id"></label>
      <input type="text" name="student_id" id="student_id">
    </p>
    <p>Password
      <label for="password"></label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit HTML like this (add onchange):

```
            <label for="user_type">Login Type:</label></td>
            <td width="271"><select name="usertype" onChange="apply(this);">
              <option value="public">Public</option>
              <option value="student"> Student</option
            </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function apply(select) {
  var publicForm = '<p>Username <label for="username"></label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p><p>Password <label for="password"></label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>';
  var studentForm = '<p>Student ID<label for="student_id"></label><input type="text" name="student_id" id="student_id"></p><p>Password <label for="password"></label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>';
  var toAdd = '';

  switch ($(select).val()) {
    case 'public':
      toAdd = publicForm;
      break;
    case 'student':
      toAdd = studentForm;
      break;
  }
  $(select).parent().append(toAdd);
}
```

Or you can create that blocks and set `display: none` for them, and then just show.